# Parsec Module not found in GHC

Tags: haskell, terminal, parsec

I keep getting the error:

```
error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Expr’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I have the newest haskell/ghc and have run `cabal install parsec` && `stack install parsec`

no matter what i do it cannot find the module

EDIT:

Can you post the command line? Have you listed it in your cabal file? – Paul Johnson 3 mins ago

it was my first install of cabal so it said it would generate the file for me.

cmd line

```
    PA1Helper.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Text.Parsec
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PA1Helper.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.String’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Text.Parsec.String
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PA1Helper.hs:5:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Expr’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import Text.Parsec.Expr
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PA1Helper.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Token’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import Text.Parsec.Token
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PA1Helper.hs:7:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Language’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
7 | import Text.Parsec.Language
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PA1Helper.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Char’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
8 | import Text.Parsec.Char
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also the output of stack exec -- ghc-pkg list would be helpful:

```
Cabal-1.24.2.0
array-0.5.1.1
base-4.9.1.0
binary-0.8.3.0
bytestring-0.10.8.1
containers-0.5.7.1
deepseq-1.4.2.0
directory-1.3.0.0
filepath-1.4.1.1
ghc-8.0.2
ghc-boot-8.0.2
ghc-boot-th-8.0.2
ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
ghci-8.0.2
haskeline-0.7.3.0
hoopl-3.10.2.1
hpc-0.6.0.3
integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
pretty-1.1.3.3
process-1.4.3.0
rts-1.0
template-haskell-2.11.1.0
terminfo-0.4.0.2
time-1.6.0.1
transformers-0.5.2.0
unix-2.7.2.1
xhtml-3000.2.1
/Users/hannahdeen/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.5/8.0.2/pkgdb
    mtl-2.2.1
    parsec-3.1.11
    text-1.2.2.2
/Users/hannahdeen/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.5/8.0.2/pkgdb
    (no packages)
```

Comment: Can you post the command line? Have you listed it in your cabal file?

Comment: Also the output of `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list` would be helpful

Comment: updated to answer questions

Comment: What command are you using to compile your program? If you're in a cabal project (using `cabal build` or `stack build`) you must add parsec as a dependency in the .cabal file.